# GSON Double Rounding when adding in HashSet

Tags: java, android, performance, gson

So I am parsing a VERY large JSON file with the use of GSON.
The class I'm parsing it into is structure like this:

What I'm trying to do is round the doubles (in the HashSet, in the Geometry class) up to to 4 decimal points. So as doubles are being added to the HashSet, I want to round them up.

```
public class Contours {

    public String name = null;
    public String type = null;
    ArrayList<Features> features = null;

    class Features {
        public String type = null;
        public Geometry geometry = null;
        public Properties properties = null;
    }

    class Geometry {
        public String type = null;
        HashSet<double[]> coordinates = null;
    }

    class Properties {
        public String CONTOUR = null;
        public int OBJECTID;
        public String LAYER = null;
        public double ELEVATION;
    }

}
```

### Why I can't do this iteratively after GSON has parsed the file?

The file is VERY large, and has 412,064 lines and is 27.5mb large. So doing that will take very long time.

NOTE: this parsing happens every time this app is run, so speed is necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you should not round all data when you parse It. Try to  create a method Wrapper that will be return double rounded to 4 decimal when you get double from coordinates. It help you to save performance

Comment: A side note: Your ` = null` adds no value. Neither to the machine (reference fields are initialized to `null`, anyway; the produced bytecode is identical), nor to humans (it's just clutter; why don't you initialize the other fields?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a `TypeAdapter` to modify values as they're read:

```
public class GsonDoubleAdapterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new DoubleAdapter());

        Gson gson = builder.create();
        Foo foo = gson.fromJson("{\"baz\": 0.123456}", Foo.class);
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}

/**
 * A type adapter that rounds doubles during read.
 */
class DoubleAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Double> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Double value) throws IOException {
        out.value(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Double read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return new BigDecimal(in.nextDouble()).setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    }
}

class Foo {
    private Double baz;

    public Double getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(Double baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo[baz=" + baz + ']';
    }
}
```